# SQL Server datetime Format Isn't Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

`TimeOpened` is a column in my dataase table of type `datetime2`.

My convert statement is:

```
convert(nvarchar, TimeOpened, 114)
```

My output is supposed to be just the time (24 hours based) without the date, i.e.

```
5/16/2016 1:38:00 PM --> 13:38:00
```

but in practice the output I get is `01:38:00`

Why is this happening?

Additionally I would like to know how to remove the seconds. Basically I want my output to be `13:38`.

Thanks.

Comment: Have your tried `convert(nvarchar,TimeOpened,108)`?

Comment: I've just tried and it gets time in 24 hour format

Comment: Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: try it 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),108),5)

Comment: To get only HH:MM, you can do this: `SELECT (TimeOpened),substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TimeOpenede, 108),0,6) AS Time  from yourtable`

Comment: ok when I use     convert(nvarchar,gettime(),108) it works but when i use convert(nvarchar,TimeOpened,108) it wont work. very wired.

Comment: Why not just select the datetime as is and format the display in the presentation layer?

Comment: Are you sure your `TimeOpened`column is `DateTime`? Because that's really weird

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
The problem was that when I inserted the date I used c# datetime.now instead of getdate()

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (SQL Server 2012 or later):

```
SELECT FORMAT(TimeOpened,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

For sql server 2008 you can cast to `time` and then convert to `char(5)`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(5), CAST(TimeOpened As Time))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast(TimeOpened as time),N'hh\.mm') as mytime
```

you can see more examples on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx#ExampleD

Comment: Format was already suggested and rejected since the OP works with a version that is older than 2012...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,TimeOpened,108),5)
```